# Device to Device Notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I'm  a newbie iOS developer and trying to implement device to device notification in iOS something to handle friend requests etc.. I'm looking for documentation that guides me in the process. I'm using firebase as my backend system but I'm cannot find any documentation about device to device notification . I also checked out One Signal but still having hard time figuring out how this is implemented , Can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Finding off-site tutorials is typically off-topic here on Stack Overflow. That said (shameless self-plug) you could do worse than using the approach described in this post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html It's for Android, but the Android-specific parts are fairly small and easily portable to iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to implement this logic with server-side code using one of Firebase's server SDKs. You can look their [fantastic documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

hope it help:

OS X and iOS application and framework to play with the Apple Push Notification service (APNs)

https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher