# Device to device push notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it now possible to send push notifications from client iOS device to another iOS device without additional server - only using Firebase Cloud Messaging? I know it can be done through the Firebase console, but can it be done from an iOS device? There are similar stackoveflow questions, that claim it was not possible before, but can be already done. If it's possible - please provide an example - only for the sending part.

Comment: Sending messages *to* a device requires that you specify the so-called FCM server key. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a server, or an environment you otherwise control. For an example of this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087505/device-to-device-notifications-in-ios, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716/209103 or my blog post here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the response and interesting blog post. If you add your response as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Good to hear it was helpful. The questions I linked are the same, so I voted to close your question as a duplicate instead